# bash $1 inside command from function

Tags: bash, function, arguments

Could somebody give advise how the situation can be resolved:

I call function with arg:

```
funct $size
```

Then I need to run bash command inside the function

```
function funct {
    arg=$1
    files=(`find /var/ -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d -exec du -bs {} \; |  awk '$1>$arg'`)
}
```

The problem is with `awk '$1>$arg'`
I always get `awk '$size>$size'`, not `$1` from `find-du` result.

Could somebody help?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have any interest in an answer that's less broken (ie. works correctly with directory names with spaces, globs, etc)?

Comment: ...to be clear, `array=( $(...) )` or its less-modern equivalent ```array=( `...` )``` is almost always going to have bugs in it: Unquoted expansions (which are how it's splitting items into individual elements) go through both string-splitting on characters in IFS and glob expansion (meaning that if you have a whitespace-surrounded `*` anywhere in output, it gets replaced with content of the current directory). The right way to populate an array is with `read -a`, `mapfile`, `readarray`, or a `while read` loop.

Comment: ...as another aside, consider avoiding the `function` keyword. It's incompatible with baseline POSIX shells (for which the appropriate syntax to declare a function is `funct() {` -- no preceding `function` keyword, and with an appended `()` being mandatory), but -- unlike more useful bashisms -- gives you no benefit over the compatible/standardized syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell won't expand `$arg` because it is in single-quotes.  For the find-awk pipeline, try:

```
find /var/ -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d -exec du -bs {} \; |  awk -v arg="$arg" '$1>arg'
```

Here, `-v arg="$arg"` creates an awk variable called `arg` and assigns to it the value of the shell variable `arg`.

Note that, if any of the directory names have white space in them,  the array `files` will probably not be what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

func get $size as $1... if you want to use $1 (as you get outside of func) just pass it to func as an additional argument, let's say arg2?

Then compare $arg2> $size.

It will solve your problem :)
* it happens because $1 is a local variable for each context. The func and where func is called are different contexts so $1 has different meaning.